# When i deserializeUser in passportJS the user does not get passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have this issue where when i deserialize my user from my session with passport js i can get the user and pass it to passportjs. but passportjs does not seem to pass it on to my authentication code. here is my code for deserializesastion

```
passport.deserializeUser(async function (id, done) {
  console.log("Deserializing")
  User.findByPk(id).then(function (user) {
    console.log("Deserialised user" + user.Username);
    done(null, user)
  },
    function (err) {
      console.error(err);
      done(err);
    }
  )
});
```

and here is my code for my authentication

```
app.get('/api/loginTest', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local',(err, user, info) => {
    
    if (err) {
      console.error("ERROR: " + err);
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      console.error("No User" + user);
      return res.send('No User')

    }
    console.log(user);
    return res.send("Logged in");
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

and last but not least here is the console output from running this code.

```
istening at http://localhost:3000
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "Username", "Password", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."Username" = 'Frederik' LIMIT 1;
Deserializing
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "Username", "Password", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE "User"."id" = 15;
Deserialised userFrederik
No Userfalse
```

as you can see i have no problem getting the user in the deserialising function. however as soon as i try to user the user in the authentication middle ware. the user is just NULL

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. I just needed to use `req.user` instead of `user`

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/